# History of experimental verification of the identity of voltaic and static electricity and references

Tags: physics, electricity

What where the crucial experiments which showed  the identity of voltaic and static electricity? How did the experiments work in detail and what are the original references for it?

In "[A History of the Theories of Aether and Electricity - The Classical Theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_History_of_the_Theories_of_Aether_and_Electricity)" by E.T.Whittaker, I found the follwing:

> But the connection of the different branches of electric science with each other was still not altogether clear. Although Wollaston’s experiments of 1801 had in effect proved the identity in kind of the currents derived from frictional and voltaic sources, the question was still regarded as open thirty years afterwards,no satisfactory explanation being forthcoming of the fact that frictional electricity appeared to be a surface-phenomenon, whereas voltaic electricity was conducted within the interior substance of bodies. To this question Faraday now applied himself; and in 1833 he succeeded in **showing that every known effect of electricity—physiological, magnetic, luminous, calorific, chemical and mechanical—may be obtained indifferently either with the electricity which is obtained by friction or with that obtained from a voltaic battery**.

(bold mine)

In this text Whittaker seems to give a reference about what I am looking for, but I didn't find a source for it: "Exp. Ran, series iii" (what magazine is "Exp. Ran"?). In the case of Wollastons exeriment there is also a reference (Phil. Trans. xci (1801), p. 4-27). The magazine seems to be "Philosophical Transactions", but I didn't find a link to the paper as well.

Comment: The Faraday citation is his Experimental Researches series three (link: https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstl.1833.0006)